# RxJS Observables and the Right Way to architect filtered lists

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have gone through a bunch of tutorials, done demos etc.. but i'm still not able to wrap my head around the right way to do this with Observables...

Basically what i have (in angular) is 2 mutable arrays in my component, a displayList and a fullList of items...  The template does an ngFor on the displayList.

Filters on the screen call a filter function in the component that clears displayList, then loops through fullList and if the filter applies, it pushes it to display list - giving a real time list filtering effect on the screen...

I know this is the wrong way to approach this, but i cannot wrap my head around the architecture/pattern needed to do this with observables.  Do i make a main list and run a .filter() on it based on a component private property? do i do the ngFor on a method that returns the observable list with the .filter in place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unless there is some functionality you can't achieve unless you use observables I think your approach sounds fine. You could create a BehaviorSubject for your displayList e.g. `displayList = new BehaviorSubject([])` and update it with `displayList.next(newDisplayList)`. Then you could bind to it in the ngFor with `*ngFor="item in displayList | async"`. But I don't necessarily see a benefit to that approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes, no, yes, no... in other words: There is no correct answer, it depends. (On your personal, preference, on the general use-case, on the existing architecture of your application, ect. ect...)

---

**Filtering in the controller**

In your case, there might not be the need for rxjs, though you should avoid mutable objects/data if possible, so your idea with using `.filter` would be the way to go here.

---

**Custom Pipe**

Another way to go would be to implement a custom pipe and filter the data directly in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of fullList | customFilterPipe:filterSettings">...</div>
```

---

**The RxJS-Way**

Since you asked for the rxjs-way, here is how I would do it:

```
filterSettings$: BehaviorSubject<IFilterData> = new BehaviorSubject(INITIAL_FILTER_SETTINGS); // this is updated with filterSettings$.next(newFilterSettings)
fullList$: BehaviorSubject<IData[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]); // updated through fullList$.next(newFullList);
displayList$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.fullList$, this.filterSettings$)
    .map(([list, filterSettings]) => {
        return list.filter(/* your custom filter based on the filterSettings... */);
    });
```

This will automatically update the `displayList$` whenever the `filterSettings$` or the `fullList$` changes.

To use it in the templare you can use the `async`-Pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of displayList$ | async">...</div>
```

---

But again: Any of those solutions, as well as your current implementation could be a perfectly valid implementation for a given case.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

In RxJS 5 the best candidate for this is the [`combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-combineLatest) operator (it has both static and instance method variants) that calls its selector function when any of its source Observables emit a value.

```
let userInput$ = Observable.from(['a', 'ac', 'aca', 'acarp'])
  .concatMap(char => Observable.of(char).delay(500))
  .startWith(null);

let list$ = Observable.of(['abstemious', 'abstentious', 'abulia', 'abut', 'aby', 'acalculia', 'acarophobia', 'acarpous', 'accidence', 'accismus', 'acclamation']);

let filteredList$ = Observable.combineLatest(list$, userInput$, (list, filterString) => {
    if (filterString) {
      // Note that this is Array.filter() method, not an RxJS operator
      return list.filter(name => name.indexOf(filterString) === 0);
    }
    return list;
  });


filteredList$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/jihuxu/2/edit?js,console

This simulates a situation where the user types one character every 500ms and filters the `list$` accordingly. Note that also the `list$` can emit a new array that'll be filtered right away.

One important thing to be aware of is that each source Observable has to emit at least one value before `.combineLatest()` is able to emit on every change. This is why I have also the `startWith(null)`, to be sure that the selected filter is `null` at the beginning.